# CSS Transitions not adjusting height

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, transition

I'm using the 'A Collection of Page Transitions' (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/) jQuery script to use transactions when switching between pages (down > up, left > right,...).

The problem is that when for example the first page has content that is bigger than the body and a scrollbar appears like it should, the next page with no content will keep de scrollbar and unnecessary whitespace at the bottom.

Example, go from page 1 to page 2. At the bottom of page 2 their will be a lot whitespace that remained from page 1: http://netbear.be/transition/

Is it possible that after every page-transition, the height is recalculated somehow?

```
// HTML-structure
<div class="pt-wrapper">
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1">
        // content bigger than browser height creating a scrollbar (overlay: visible;)
        <div style="background: red; width: 150px; height: 2000px;"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2">
        // content smaller than browser height.
    </div>
</div>

// CSS
.pt-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-perspective: 1200px;
    -moz-perspective: 1200px;
    perspective: 1200px;
}

.pt-page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use !important for height attribute
for example: height: 100% !important;
if this not working you must create a div and use absolute and relative for fixed the height.

Comment: I think the height: 100% is already applied. But because there is no refresh when the pages are switching, the height of the content/body does not gets recalculated so it still thinks there is need for a scrollbar when it goes to a page with no content.